# UITextView text is missing when adjust frame according to text in iOS7?

Tags: ios7, uitextview, frame, cgsize

Hi I am trying to set UITextView height as per content. Its working fine for adjusting frame of UITextView.

But coming to text is missing as like below image shown. This happn only in iOS7 . Its displaying well in iOS6. If i tap on textview i started to edit the textview complete text is dispalying.

I wrote the fllowing lines of code`  notesField.text = [editWellObject objectForKey:@"Notes"];

```
// Adjusting Frame as per text
CGSize size = [notesField sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(notesField.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
CGRect frame = notesField.frame;
float difference = size.height - frame.size.height;
frame.size.height = size.height;
notesField.frame = frame;
```

Please help me in this issue. Thanks in Advance.
[image]

Comment: I also had same problem so i increased height by 10 ie its addtional to size.height. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks Prince for your response. But here UITextView frame is more from text. Here green layer border is there beyonds textview. That means it had frame until bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few days back I was struggling with the same issue and I have found solution with resetting property scrollEnable from NO to YES. Following is my code snippet

```
    internalTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    if (newSizeH >= maxHeight)
        internalTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you @Raman Soni 
will you please exaplain what is newSizeH ?

Comment: Its variable that stores your text dynamic height. Here is complete code snippet:

CGSize dynamicSize = [uitextviewinstance.text sizeWithFont:uitextviewinstance.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(uitextviewinstance.frame.size.width-uitextviewinstance.contentInset.left-uitextviewinstance.contentInset.right, constraintHeight) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        float newSizeH = size.height;


internalTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    if (newSizeH >= maxHeight)
        internalTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;


Note: maxHeight is max height allowed for uitextviewinstance on UI